# Xcode Prefix header is not compiling

Tags: xcode, xcode8, header-files

Xcode - my .pch is not compiling while I try to  run the application. 
I tried to put a line with a dummy library(not_available.h), I found that the compiler do not show error.

```
#import <aaa/not_available.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>
#import <QuickbloxWebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.h>
```

I have set  Prefix header to Yes
and tried different values to the area Pre-compiled path.

I am using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no .pch option in Swift, instead you have to bridge the files

```
@import UIKit;
@import Foundation;
@import SystemConfiguration;
@import MobileCoreServices;

#import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>
#import <QuickbloxWebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.h>
```